# Python: Need help solving this problem using two pointers method

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, debugging, data-structures

I'm currently practicing coding problems and found this problem called "Successful Pairs of Spells and Potions", the problem describtion is as follows;

You are given two positive integer arrays spells and potions, of length `n` and `m` respectively, where `spells[i]` represents the strength of the `ith` spell and `potions[j]` represents the strength of the `jth` potion.

You are also given an integer success. A spell and potion pair is considered successful if the product of their strengths is at least success.

Return an integer array pairs of length n where `pairs[i]` is the number of potions that will form a successful pair with the ith spell.

```
Example 1:

Input: spells = [5,1,3], potions = [1,2,3,4,5], success = 7
Output: [4,0,3]
Explanation:
- 0th spell: 5 * [1,2,3,4,5] = [5,10,15,20,25]. 4 pairs are successful.
- 1st spell: 1 * [1,2,3,4,5] = [1,2,3,4,5]. 0 pairs are successful.
- 2nd spell: 3 * [1,2,3,4,5] = [3,6,9,12,15]. 3 pairs are successful.
Thus, [4,0,3] is returned.

Example 2:

Input: spells = [3,1,2], potions = [8,5,8], success = 16
Output: [2,0,2]
Explanation:
- 0th spell: 3 * [8,5,8] = [24,15,24]. 2 pairs are successful.
- 1st spell: 1 * [8,5,8] = [8,5,8]. 0 pairs are successful. 
- 2nd spell: 2 * [8,5,8] = [16,10,16]. 2 pairs are successful. 
Thus, [2,0,2] is returned.
```

I know that this problem could be solved using `binary search`, but my attempt was an iterative attempt which counts the total of each successful element in each `array` and inserts them into another array. but for some reason my returned array is all zero's `([0,0,0])`. here is my attempt. I would appreciate any help on finding the bug in my solution, just trying to learn, thanks.

```html
    def successfulPairs(self, spells, potions, success):
        arr = []
        total = 0
        first = 0
        second = 0
        
        while first < len(spells):
            res = spells[first] * potions[second]
            for i in range(len(potions)):
                if res >= success:
                    total += 1
                    second += 1
            first += 1
            arr.append(total)
            total = 0
        return arr
```

Comment: What does this have to do with pointers? Python doesn't have pointers.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the variables 'first = 0' and 'second = 0' are treated like pointers and move along the two arrays.

Comment: Those are called indexes.

Comment: You're not using `i` in the `for` loop. You keep testing the same value of `res` each time.

Comment: @Barmar could you show me how you I could fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop keeps testing the same value of `res` each time through the loop. Incrementing `second` doesn't change the value of `res`.

You don't need to use pointers (indexes), just iterate through the list elements. You can use the `sum()` function to calculate the total, and a generator expression to iterate through the list of potions and do the multiplication.

```
def successfulPairs(self, spells, potions, success):
    arr = []
    for spell in spells:
        total = sum(spell * potion >= success for potion in potions)
        arr.append(total)
    return arr
```